# How to remove an unreferenced object from array

Tags: javascript

I have an object that looks like this:

```
obj = {"students":[{"name":"Jenna","grade":"B"}, {"name":"Alex","grade":"C"}]}
```

I want to delete one of the objects that I will reference like this:

```
delete obj.students[0]
```

This should delete the first object `{"name":"Jenna","grade":"B"}` from the students object but it doesn't.

Comment: That is JavaScript, not JSON

Comment: It *does* delete that: https://jsbin.com/kototob/1/edit?js,console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `delete` operator for objects, not arrays.

> The JavaScript delete operator removes a property from an object; if no more references to the same property are held, it is eventually released automatically. ([mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete))

For arrays, there are a number of alternatives, the easiest in this case being `splice` ([mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)), which conveniently allows removing (or adding) a variable number of consecutive elements starting at the specified index.

```js
let obj = {"students":[{"name":"Jenna","grade":"B"}, {"name":"Alex","grade":"C"}]};
obj.students.splice(0, 1);

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is called [`Array.shift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift).

> The shift() method *removes the first element from an array* and returns that removed element. This method changes the length of the array.

```js
obj = {
  "students": [{
    "name": "Jenna",
    "grade": "B"
  }, {
    "name": "Alex",
    "grade": "C"
  }]
};
obj.students.shift();
console.log(obj)
```

Comment: That's good to know but I wanted was to remove any element of choice and not just the first. Maybe I wasn't clear with my question :D Thanks for the help anyway!

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript delete operator deletes a property from an **object**. You can find more about this on [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_remove_property_object.asp) :

For e.g. to delete last name from the "Employee" object :

```
var Employee = {
  firstname: "John",
  lastname: "Doe"
};

delete Employee.firstname;
```

To delete an element from an array - array methods like splice(), pop(), shift() can be used based on the requirement. Refer [GeeksForGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/javascript-basic-array-methods/) for more information.

For your case, you can use either :

```
var obj = {"students":[{"name":"Jenna","grade":"B"}, {"name":"Alex","grade":"C"}]};
obj.students.shift();
```

Or,

```
var obj = {"students":[{"name":"Jenna","grade":"B"}, {"name":"Alex","grade":"C"}]};
obj.students.splice(0,1);
```